# Elasticsearch for python - Get documents deleted by query

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm using Elasticsearch in python, and I can't figure out how to get the ids of the documents deleted by the `delete_by_query()` method! By default it only the number of documents deleted.

There is a parameter called `_source` that if set to `True` should return the source of the deleted documents. This doesn't happen, nothing changes.

Is there a good way to know which document where deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delete by query endpoint only returns a macro summary of what happened during the task, mainly how many documents were deleted and [some other details](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html#_response_body).

If you want to know the IDs of the document that are going to be deleted, you can do a search (with `_source: false`) before running the delete by query operation and you'll get the expected IDs.

Comment: But that seems very inefficient... :(

Comment: Yes, but delete by query can potentially delete millions of documents, so it makes sense that ES is not returning the IDs in the response.